# Docker: How to share a folder between two containers

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I am working on app that has a webserver running openresty and a application running on php wit the front-end in vue.

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./services/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

  web:
    build: ./services/openresty
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - ./services/openresty/company.conf:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
      - ./services/openresty/bodyconfig.conf:/etc/openresty/nginx/conf/bodyconfig.conf
```

When building the application I am building my vue code to a dist folder this happens inside the php container:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update \
    && apk add  --no-cache git curl libmcrypt libmcrypt-dev openssh-client icu-dev \
    libxml2-dev bash freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev nodejs npm libzip-dev g++ make autoconf postgresql-dev \
    && docker-php-source extract \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql soap intl gd zip \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]

WORKDIR /var/www/company

COPY ./ ./

RUN bash ./docker_build.sh

EXPOSE 9000
```

docker_build.sh

```
cd /var/www/company/js

npm install
npm run build
```

now inside the php docker container is a new folder dist under /var/www/dist.

nginx needs to use this folder because it contains a static index.html which is served by nginx like this

```
location / {
    alias /var/www/company/dist/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

I am wondering how I can my web container access the build folder dist which is located inside the php container

Thanks in advance

Comment: @7_R3X investigating how to implement this in my current setup. Still new to docker ;)

Comment: After `services` section of the docker-compose file, you need to add a `volumes` section, define a volume and map that volume to both the services. Take a look at [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference)

Comment: @7_R3X just found it and implemented it, it works. thank you very much will accept your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [bind-mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to mount that folder from the host.

> **Bind mount**
>
> When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is
>   mounted into a container. The file or directory is referenced by its
>   full or relative path on the host machine.

Or, you can use [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and attach that volume to both the containers.

> **Docker Volume**
>
> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by
>   and used by Docker containers. While bind-mounts are dependent on the
>   directory structure of the host machine, volumes are completely
>   managed by Docker.

Edit:
Link to [Official document of docker-volume implementation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference)